# получить данные от веб-сервера в переменную по ip адресу

Tags: php, ip

При наборе `IPv4` адреса в адресной строке браузера, получаю две строки сообщения ввиде `html` кода, т.е. таблица с данными которые динамически меняются при каждом запросе.

Как можно заполучить эти данные, и сохранить в `php` переменную

Comment: `file_get_contents($ip)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
```